# How to iterate over script arguments?

Tags: unix, powershell, command-line-arguments, shift

In Unix shell scripts one can use something like this for parsing the arguments to the script:

```sh
while [ $1 ]; do
  #
  # do stuff
  #
  shift
done
```

How do I implement something similar in PowerShell?

Comment: you did not actually explain your problem, I think. At any rate, it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, I don't agree that the question needs *that* much clarification, although it is awkwardly worded. He clearly wants to know if he can iterate over the argument list of a PowerShell script like it's done in Unix/Linux shells.

Comment: In PowerShell one would process the arguments collection `$args` with a loop, e.g. `foreach ($a in $args) { ... }` or `$args | % { ... }`.

Comment: Besides, you shouldn't be using `while [ $1 ]` + `shift` (not to mention: not quoting `$1` is 1 of the worst mistake you can make) cuz NIX shells ain't Batch, you can just use `for _i in "${@}"`.

Answer (score 4):

For undeclared parameters, you can use the `$Args` [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) as @AnsgarWeichers suggests with either of the foreach methods (see below), but I would argue the Unix method you're describing is against PowerShell philosophy.  PowerShell is a .Net environment, so everything is fundamentally an object instead of fundamentally a character string.

You should be defining your parameters, giving them a type, and, above all, giving them a *name*.  See [about_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847824.aspx), [about_Functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx), [about_Functions_Advanced](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx), and [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx).  A script can be written to function like a cmdlet or function, so that's why you look to those help docs.

If your parameter is legitimately an array, you can iterate through it with either the [foreach statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847816.aspx):

```
foreach ($item in $MyParameterArray) {
    [...]
}
```

Or using the [ForEach-Object cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bea187c1-37b5-4fc7-9422-d29820643a4d(v=wps.640).aspx):

```
$MyParameterArray | ForEach-Object {
    [...]
}
```